# Determine Win or Loss of each game and record to that teams list

Tags: excel

I have all my other formulas figured out but I'm stuck on 1 particular that actually produces the W or L.

[The schedule](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tt8IL.png)

What I'm trying to do on a separate sheet is, regardless of the home (left) or away (right) position, if the winner (team name) = A-row, put a W in B-row,C-row,etc. and if they lost, put an L.

Schedule sheet is Home Team in A, @ symbol in B, Away Team in C, Time in D, E is Home score and F is Away score

And here is what I'm trying to get as a final picture

[Tracker sheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/csxD4.png)

The tracker sheet also powers the streak counter, but I have a working formula for that. (it works great when I manually enter W and L on the tracker)

Thank you for taking the time to read this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image]

```
=LET(rGames;A$1:F$10;rScores;FILTER(FILTER(rGames;(FILTER(rGames;{1\0\0\0\0\0})=H2)+(FILTER(rGames;{0\0\1\0\0\0})=H2));{1\0\1\0\1\1});TRANSPOSE(BYROW(rScores;LAMBDA(rowGame;IF((INDEX(rowGame;1;1)=H2)*(INDEX(rowGame;1;3)>INDEX(rowGame;1;4))+(INDEX(rowGame;1;2)=H2)*(INDEX(rowGame;1;3)<INDEX(rowGame;1;4));"W";"L")))))
```

The formulae will calculate and spill W & L for the Team given in the respective cells in column H.
The order is according to the games plan from top to bottom.
For error handling (e.g. missing results of open games) you can adjust the IF clause accordingly.

Edit: due to regional settings might want to replace `;` and `\` with `,`

Edit2: put an “o” when one of the result cells is empty (per match)

```
=LET(rGames;A$1:F$10;rTeams;H$2:H$5;rScores;FILTER(FILTER(rGames;(FILTER(rGames;{1\0\0\0\0\0})=H2)+(FILTER(rGames;{0\0\1\0\0\0})=H2));{1\0\1\0\1\1});rowWL;TRANSPOSE(BYROW(rScores;LAMBDA(rowGame;IF(ISBLANK(INDEX(rowGame;1;3))+ISBLANK(INDEX(rowGame;1;4));"o";IF((INDEX(rowGame;1;1)=H2)*(INDEX(rowGame;1;3)>INDEX(rowGame;1;4))+(INDEX(rowGame;1;2)=H2)*(INDEX(rowGame;1;3)<INDEX(rowGame;1;4));"W";"L"))))); rowWL)
```

Comment: {0\0\1\0\0\0}) is throwing an error. And beyond that, I would need to put in 2624 0's and 1's. There are 1,312 games for the season with each team having 82 games. Thank you but this will not be a workable formula

Comment: As shown in the screenshot it works. The {..} is just to select the respective columns (not rows) from A to F. You can replace \ with , (depending on regional settings)

Comment: it still is not working.  https://i.imgur.com/thyri2G.png

Comment: If there is no mis-spelling, it seems your Excel version does not support one of the function, e.g. the BYROW?

Comment: making progress!! I had to do a pretty large update (2106 to 2206).

Pretty close now. The problem now is it is marking blanks (games not played) as L

Comment: See last edit as example to put “o” for cases if one of the scores of a match is missing.

Comment: GENIOUS!!!!!!! Thank you so much for this!!! Edit 2 was the perfect answer. I cannot thank you enough for your effort and willingness to stick around and help me out with this :-)